# How do you compile Pango on Amazon Linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, compiler-errors, aws-lambda, pango

I'm trying to compile a recent version of Pango (1.38 or later) on Amazon Linux 2017.9, the end goal being to compile a version of librsvg.

`./configure` doesn't give any errors, and I think I have all dependencies installed. However when I run `make` I get loads of warnings, and some errors.

Some examples:

Warnings:

```
pango-renderer.c:1463: Warning: Pango: invalid annotation option: nullable
pango-utils.c:131: Warning: Pango: invalid annotation option: nullable
pango-engine.h:123: Warning: Pango: invalid annotation option: nullable
pango-engine.h:170: Warning: Pango: missing ':' at column 20:
 * PangoEngineShape
```

Errors:

```
autofit.c:(.text+0x82a6): undefined reference to `hb_buffer_create'
/home/ec2-user/build/lib/libfreetype.a(autofit.o): In function `af_shaper_buf_destroy':
/home/ec2-user/freetype-2.9/src/autofit/afshaper.c:441: undefined reference to `hb_buffer_destroy'
/home/ec2-user/build/lib/libfreetype.a(autofit.o): In function `af_shaper_buf_create':
autofit.c:(.text+0x6701): undefined reference to `hb_buffer_create'
/home/ec2-user/build/lib/libfreetype.a(autofit.o): In function `af_shaper_buf_destroy':
autofit.c:(.text+0x6714): undefined reference to `hb_buffer_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
linking of temporary binary failed: Command '['/bin/sh', '../libtool', '--mode=link', '--tag=CC', '--silent', 'gcc', '-o', '/home/ec2-user/pango-1.39.0/pango/tmp-introspect84YaJG/Pango-1.0', '-export-dynamic', '/home/ec2-user/pango-1.39.0/pango/tmp-introspect84YaJG/Pango-1.0.o', '-L.', 'libpango-1.0.la', '-Wl,--export-dynamic', '-pthread', '-L/home/ec2-user/build/lib', '-lgio-2.0', '-lgmodule-2.0', '-lgobject-2.0', '-lcairo', '-lglib-2.0', '-lfreetype']' returned non-zero exit status 1
make[4]: *** [Pango-1.0.gir] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the warnings come from the gobject-introspection step of the build.

Those errors indicate a missing harfbuzz library.